# classic asp ignore comma within speech marks CSV

Tags: regex, csv, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a CSV File that looks like this 

1,HELLO,ENGLISH

2,HELLO1,ENGLISH

3,HELLO2,ENGLISH

4,HELLO3,ENGLISH

5,HELLO4,ENGLISH

6,HELLO5,ENGLISH

7,HELLO6,ENGLISH

8,"HELLO7, HELLO7 ...",ENGLISH

9,HELLO7,ENGLISH

10,HELLO7,ENGLISH

I want to step loop through the lines and write to a table using split classic asp function by comma. When Speech marks are present to ignore the comma within those speech marks and take the string.

```
<%
dim csv_to_import,counter,line,fso,objFile
csv_to_import="uploads/testLang.csv"   
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set objFile = fso.opentextfile(server.mappath(csv_to_import))
str_imported_data="<table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' border='1'>"

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream


  line = split(objFile.ReadLine,",")    
  str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<tr>"
  total_records=ubound(line)

  for i=0 to total_records
    if i>0 then
     str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<td>"&line(i)&"</td>"
    else
     str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<th>"&line(i)&"</th>"
    end if
next
  str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"</tr>" & chr(13)


Loop
str_imported_data=str_imported_data&"<caption>Total Number of Records: "&total_records&"</caption></table>"
objFile.Close
response.Write str_imported_data
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Don't write your own CSV parser.](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)

You start with "splitting it on the `,` is the way to go, now I am finished". Then someone uses a comma in your data and the string with the comma is surrounded by double quotes. You are a smart man, so you count the amount of double quotes and if they are odd, you know you have to escape the comma and if they are even, you don't have to. And then you get a CSV file containing escaped double quote characters...

But wait! There is a solution. Use a [Database Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) to your file!

It will be something like this, but you'll have to adapt it to your own situation:

```
On Error Resume Next
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strPathtoTextFile = server.mappath("uploads/")
strFileName = "testLang.csv"

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strPathtoTextFile & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=CSVDelimited"""

objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strFileName, _
          objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo "Number: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item(1)
    Wscript.Echo "Greeting: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item(2)
    Wscript.Echo "Language: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item(3)   
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```